# django: correctly retrieve data where date and time are greater than now

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model which describes an event like this:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    time = models.TimeField()
```

I would like to retrieve all future events (ie date greater than `now.date()`). However If date is today, I would like to retrieve today's events with time greater than `now.time()`.

This is what I am doing:

```
events = Event.objects.filter(date__gte=now.date()).filter(time__gte=now.time()).order_by('-date')
```

where `now = datetime.datetime.now()`

But this is wrong, because it gives me an empty set if the only event is tomorrow and its time is less than current time (for example if event is tomorrow at 09:00 and today is 19:00)

is this possible in django?

PS: I would like to avoid iterating through the set.

Comment: Why are you using two separate fields to save the date and the time? Why not just one datetime field? That way you can simply query a single field instead of two.

Comment: @pastylegs suppose that you decide the day of an event before finalising the time. You could set the time to midnight (or other) to show that the time wasn't known, but it might be more convenient to have a separate time field and store None. The downside is that it makes queries like the op's more awkward.

Comment: didn't think of that - good point

Comment: @pastylegs I know. I have to do it that way (at least for the moment) because data in the database are streamlined through another source. It is not mine to handle.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use [`Q`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) objects, which allow you to make queries with OR statements.

```
from django.db.models import Q
Events = Event.objects.filter(
    Q(date=now.date(),
    time__gte=now.time()
    |Q(date__gt=now.date())
).order_by('-date')
```

Note that you might want to sort on the `time` field as well:

```
order_by('-date', '-time')
```

Comment: I tried to use Q object, but I wasn't doing it the right way. What you did is right. Thanks!

Comment: Update for Django 1.5.1:
`from django.db.models import Q`

But this is unnecessary if you just use the DateTimeField:
`events = Event.objects.filter(date__gt=datetime.now()).order_by('-date')`

Comment: @RyanAllen I don't think Django 1.5 affects the original question or answer. There were `DateTimeField`s in earlier versions of Django as well, but the OP had to use two separate fields, as discussed in the comments above.

Answer (score 2):

*What i did when i had a similar problem:*
*My Problem is to find **Upcoming events** and **Past events** from my event section and i sloved like this...*
**<---#Problemsolving #Datefiltering #Django #Backend --->**

```
@api_view(["GET"])
@check_mode## Heading ##
def past_events(request):
    profile_data = get_current_profile(request)
    profile_id = profile_data["user_profile_data"]["user_profile_pk"]
    today = date.today()

    if Event.objects.filter(event_user=profile_id,end_date__lt=today).exists():
        instances = Event.objects.filter(event_user=profile_id,end_date__lt=today)

        serialized_data = EventSerializer(
            instances, 
            context = {
                "request": request
            },
            many = True
        ).data

        response_data = {
            "Statuscode":6000,
            "data" : serialized_data,
            "title": "Past event"
            }
    else:
        response_data = {
            "StatusCode" :6001,
            "title" : "Failed",
            "message" : "Events not found" 
        }
    return Response(response_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

@api_view(["GET"])
@check_mode
def upcoming_events(request):
    profile_data = get_current_profile(request)
    profile_id = profile_data["user_profile_data"]["user_profile_pk"]
    today = date.today()

    

    if Event.objects.filter(event_user=profile_id,start_date__gt=today).exists():
        instances = Event.objects.filter(event_user=profile_id,start_date__gt=today)

        serialized_data = EventSerializer(
            instances, 
            context = {
                "request": request
            },
            many = True
        ).data

        response_data = {
            "Statuscode":6000,
            "data" : serialized_data,
            "title": "Upcoming event"
            }
    else:
        response_data = {
            "StatusCode" :6001,
            "title" : "Failed",
            "message" : "Events not found" 
        }
    return Response(response_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```